# How to include urls file from sub sub folder in django

Tags: django, django-urls

i try to include urls from my Api folder
i tried `path('api/', include("main.Apps.Api.apps.urls"))` but it doesn't work
in my `settings.py` i add the app by `INSTALLED_APPS += ["main.Apps.Api.apps.ApiConfig"]`
and i changed the app name in Api.apps.py to `name = 'MikeWebsite.Apps.Api'` Everything works
But include the urls return me
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MikeWebsite.Apps.Api.apps.urls'; 'MikeWebsite.Apps.Api.apps' is not a package`

my project file tree look like this

```
main
  └───_main
      ├── __init__.py
      ├── settings.py
      ├── urls.py
      ├── wsgi.py
      └──_Apps
         ├──_Api
         |  └── urls.py
         └── ...
```

What I'm doing is wrong?

And if you have a good source of information on how to work with apps nested in Django

Comment: `main.Apps.Api.apps.urls`? Shouldn't it be `main.Apps.Api.urls` according to the directory tree you show? Also make sure the directories `Apps` and `Api` both have an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: D'oh!‎ now i see yes you right thanks